# Can't make a tk image Button with IPython Notebook

Tags: image, button, ipython, tk-toolkit, jupyter

I'm using an IPython notebook to create a Tk application in Python.  I can make a button with a text label:

```
%matplotlib tk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text = 'IPython')
button.pack()
```

But if I try to make a button with an image I get an error message.  This code works fine when run from the command line, but crashes when executed in an IPython Notebook:

```
%matplotlib tk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='IPy_header.gif')
print(img)
button = tk.Button(root, image = img)    
button.pack()
```

The print statement verifies the PhotoImage object was created (i.e. no 'file not found' errors).  The call to tk.Button leads to this error:

```
TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

I'm using ipython/jupyter 3.0.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Is ipython running on the same machine? What is the current working directory in the ipython environment? What happens if you use the full path to the image file? Can you get the size of the image (width, height) prior to using it in the button?

Comment: Same machine, notebook is in the same directory as the image.  Yes, I can call img.height() and img.width() to get attributes, and they are what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable the tk event loop with `%gui tk`

[magic-gui](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-gui) documentation.